# What is the syntax to raise an error in c#?

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

in python you could do something like this

```
    def divide(numerator, denominator):
        if numerator == denominator:
            raise(ZeroDivisionError)
```

what would the equivalent by in c# be?

Comment: `throw new ZeroDivisionException()` where ZeroDivisionException is a class that inherits from `Exception`

Comment: Exception Handling

Comment: also `1/0` will raise the same exception ;)

Comment: What you are *generally asking about* is [Creating and Throwing Exceptions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions).

Comment: Are you asking *specifically* about division by zero, or about in general how to throw an exception? In C# dividing by the integer zero already gives an exception; you don't have to throw it yourself.  Dividing by a float zero gives an infinity or NaN float as a result.

Comment: I note that if you typed the title of your question into a search engine, you'd get the documentation explaining it. **Please do research before you post questions here.**  Describe the research you did, and say why it didn't help answer your question.

Comment: `throw new DivideByZeroException()`

Comment: Also, read [DivideByZeroException Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 3):

> What is the syntax to raise an error in c#?

What you are *generally asking about* is [Creating and Throwing Exceptions (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions).

Excerpt:

> Exceptions are used to indicate that an error has occurred while running the program. Exception objects that describe an error are created and then thrown with the throw keyword. The runtime then searches for the most compatible exception handler.

```
class ProgramLog
{
  System.IO.FileStream logFile = null;
  void OpenLog(System.IO.FileInfo fileName, System.IO.FileMode mode) {}

  void WriteLog()
  {
    if (!this.logFile.CanWrite)
    {
      throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Logfile cannot be read-only");
    }
    // Else write data to the log and return.
  }
}
```

The actual *answer to your question* is to use the keyword [throw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw).

Generally it's used like:

```
throw new Exception();
throw new ArgumentNullException();
throw new DivideByZeroException();
```

and in the case when you want to [*rethrow* the exception after you catch it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#re-throwing-an-exception):

```
throw;
```

Now there are few things to consider when throwing exceptions; [does the exception exist already](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/compiler-generated-exceptions) and what exception should I consider throwing.  I would suggest reading [Eric Lippert's Blog - Vexing exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) regarding what you should consider catching and throwing.

Comment: Pay special attention to the syntax of `throw;`.  A common mistake is to rethrow an exception using `throw ex;` . The linked documentation does warn against this error.  [Eric Lippert's Blog - Too Much Reuse](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/03/04/too-much-reuse/) discusses this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated based on comments received-**

This is how you could write exception handling specially handle devide by zero in C# -

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int number1 = 3000;
        int number2 = 0;
        try
        {
            divide(number1, number2);
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Division error.");
        }

    }

    static void divide(int numerator, int denominator)
    {
        var devideResult = numerator / denominator;

    }
```

More on this -

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dividebyzeroexception?view=netframework-4.7.2][1]

*This exception is used when-*

> The exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to divide an
>   integral or Decimal value by zero.

Comment: Why would `numerator==denominator` throw an exception... and a DivideByZeroException at that? The result in that case would be `1`. Clearly that should check for `denominator==0` instead

Comment: Yes true..That was added to demonstrate any kind of exception. I have placed the side note telling where it should be used. Thanks for letting know.

Comment: I have updated the answer according to the comments. In case of python "ZeroDivisionError raised when the second argument of a division or modulo operation is zero.", so I wanted to demonstrate earlier for exception handling

Comment: For extra points, consider also catching `OverflowException`.  `int number1 = Int32.MinValue;int number2 = -1;` may throw an overflow exception (this is implementation-defined), since it is equal to `Int32.MaxValue+1`.

Comment: @MaheshB: My comment was primarily intended as interesting errata; I did not intend to suggest that you modify your answer.  Given the OP's experience level with C#, I think this change obscures the main point of your answer.  I admit that the tone of my comment did not carry across text. Honestly, I wouldn't expect the -1/MinValue exception to be of substantial concern in normal line-of-business code, though I suppose it could occur due to placeholder data or as part of an [oracle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_attack) (or a timing oracle attack, if you catch the exception).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your comments, updated the answer back, But the information you shared is really useful.

Answer (score -4):

```
public int Divide(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    try
    {
        return numerator / denominator;
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException divideByZeroException)
    {
        Logger.Error("Divide by zero exception", divideByZeroException);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Logger.Error(exception);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a bad solution, as it will return zero if an exception occurred, so the caller will not be aware that there was a problem.

Comment: It also doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: Also, please don't post answers that are only code. Don't just solve the user's problem: explain why the solution works, so that they and every other reader learns something from it.